# Ошибка: бинарный "<<": не найден оператор, принимающий правый операнд типа "Polynomial<int>" ( или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует

Tags: c++, dll, library, lib

Пытаюсь сделать библиотеку полиномов. В консоли пользователя выдает ошибки. Помогите исправить, я в этом совсем не разбираюсь. Еще выдает ошибку: отсутствует оператор << соответствующий этим операндам.  ( подчеркивает -, +, *, << и getDerivative ).

Тут сами ошибки.

```
#include "MathLibrary.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#pragma comment(lib, "MathLibrary.lib")

using namespace std;

int main() {

    
    Polynomial<int> a{ 3, 1, 1 };
    Polynomial<int> b{ 1, 5, 1 };


    cout << "a = " << a << endl;
    cout << "b = " << b << endl;
    cout << "a + b = " << a + b << endl;
    cout << "a - b = " << a - b << endl;
    cout << "a * b = " << a * b << endl;
    cout << "Derivative of a = " << getDerivative(a) << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Уже библиотека. Файл h.

```
#ifdef MYDLL_EXPORTS
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>


template<typename T>
class Polynomial {
public:
    using Self = Polynomial<T>;

    Polynomial() : size{ 1 }, coefficients(new T[1]{}) {}

    explicit Polynomial(std::size_t size) : size{ size }, coefficients(new T[size]{}) {}

    Polynomial(const std::initializer_list<T>& coefficients) : size{ coefficients.size() }, coefficients{ new T[size] } {
        std::copy(coefficients.begin(), coefficients.end(), Polynomial::coefficients);
    }

    Polynomial(const Self& o) : size{ o.size }, coefficients(new T[size]{}) {
        std::copy(o.coefficients, o.coefficients + o.size, coefficients);
    }

    Self& operator=(const Self& o) {
        if (this != &o) {
            size = o.size;
            if (coefficients != o.coefficients) {
                delete[] coefficients;
                coefficients = new T[size]{};
                std::copy(o.coefficients, o.coefficients + o.size, coefficients);
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }

    Polynomial(Self&& o) noexcept : size{ std::move(o.size) }, coefficients{ std::exchange(o.coefficients, nullptr) } {}

    Self& operator=(Self&& o) noexcept {
        if (this != &o) {
            size = std::move(o.size);
            if (coefficients != o.coefficients) {
                coefficients = std::exchange(o.coefficients, nullptr);
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }

    Self& operator+=(const Self& o) {
        if (this == &o) {
            return *this;
        }
        if (o.size > size) {
            T* extended = new T[o.size]{};
            std::copy(coefficients, coefficients + size, extended);
            delete[] coefficients;
            coefficients = extended;
            size = o.size;
        }
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < o.size; ++i) {
            coefficients[i] += o.coefficients[i];
        }
        return *this; 
    }

    virtual ~Polynomial() {
        delete[] coefficients;
    }

    std::size_t getSize() const {
        return size;
    }

    T& operator[](std::size_t i) {
        return coefficients[i];
    }

    const T& operator[](std::size_t i) const {
        return coefficients[i];
    }

private:
    std::size_t size;
    T* coefficients;
};
```

Файл cpp.

```
// dllmain.cpp : Определяет точку входа для приложения DLL.

#include "pch.h" // use stdafx.h in Visual Studio 2017 and earlier
#include <utility>
#include <limits.h>
#include "MathLibrary.h"
#include <string>



BOOL APIENTRY MathLibraryMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}


template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Polynomial<T>& p) {
    for (std::size_t i = p.getSize(); i > 0; --i) {
        const T& value = p[i - 1];
        if (value >= 0) {
            out << "+";
        }
        out << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << value;
        if (i == 2) {
            out << "*x";
        }
        else if (i > 1) {
            out << "*x^" << (i - 1);
        }
    }
    return out;
}



template<typename T>
Polynomial<T> operator+(const Polynomial<T>& a, const Polynomial<T>& b) {
    if (a.getSize() < b.getSize()) {
        return operator+(b, a);
    }
    Polynomial<T> result{ a };
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < b.getSize(); ++i) {
        result[i] += b[i];
    }
    return result;
}

template<typename T>
Polynomial<T> operator-(const Polynomial<T>& a, const Polynomial<T>& b) {
    if (a.getSize() < b.getSize()) {
        return operator+(b, a);
    }
    Polynomial<T> result{ a };
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < b.getSize(); ++i) {
        result[i] -= b[i];
    }
    return result;
}

template<typename T>
Polynomial<T> multiply(const Polynomial<T>& p, const T& coefficient, std::size_t power) {
    Polynomial<T> result(p.getSize() + power);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < p.getSize(); ++i) {
        result[i + power] = p[i] * coefficient;
    }
    return result;
}

template<typename T>
Polynomial<T> operator*(const Polynomial<T>& a, const Polynomial<T>& b) {
    if (b.getSize() < a.getSize()) {
        return operator*(b, a);
    }
    Polynomial<T> result(a.getSize() + b.getSize() - 1);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < a.getSize(); ++i) {
        result += multiply(b, a[i], i);
    }
    return result;
}

template<typename T>
Polynomial<T> getDerivative(const Polynomial<T>& p) {
    if (p.getSize() == 1) {
        return Polynomial<T>{0};
    }
    Polynomial<T> result(p.getSize() - 1);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < result.getSize(); ++i) {
        result[i] = p[i + 1] * (i + 1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Конечно подчеркивает, ведь эти операторы не объявлены в подключаемом заголовочном фале.

Comment: а как правильно подключить?

Comment: @user7860670 Не тот дубликат?

Comment: Подвинуть в хедер из .cpp-шника.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Очень даже тот. Типичная реализация шаблонов в cpp файле.

Comment: @user7860670 Я бы согласился, если бы их хотя бы объявили в хедере. :) Ошибка-то другая...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ну так а если исправить ту, что есть и их объявить, то получится как раз та.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat а можете показать хотя бы как одну функцию объявить, я пробую, у меня не получается,, не до конца понимаю, как надо

Comment: Просто переместить из .cpp в .h.

Comment: оставить срр пустым? тогда пишет ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ